# Which packs provide the most value for diamonds spent?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-heroes

In Plants vs Zombies: Heroes, you can buy different card packs which cost a different number of diamonds.  There are the basic and premium packs, as well as special packs such as the Z-Mech Hero Pack and the Solar Flare Premium Pack.

Which pack is likely to return the highest value cards for the fewest number of diamonds?

Answer (score 1):

Well I would say it depends. I would go with the basic plants pack if you want some more general cards that you can use in most decks, the *insert hero here* sidekick pack if you want a bunch of cards that compliment the specific hero to implement in one of the hero's decks. Those packs are mostly quite cheap (Last time I checked most of the hero sidekick packs were around 300 gems) and you should be able to make some good decks with them. Hope I helped.